# How to consume wcf service running as windows service in ajax client

Tags: ajax, wcf

I have created a WCF service and it is hosted in windows service. When I have added a web reference to that service to an asp.net web forms project through right client menu in the solution explorer I am able to access the service and add reference to it.

Now I want to access this service through AJAX client (i.e in ASP.NET project through ScriptManager component)and call the service in a timer to get continuous stream of values.

I have never worked on AJAX or web that much, I did not find an suitable example on net on this.

I'm using WSHttpBinding.

---

I'm posting my code so that you can tell where I'm doing wrong.

WCF Service Library Code:

ITestService.cs code....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace TestServiceLibrary
{
    // NOTE: If you change the interface name "IService1" here, you must also update the reference to "IService1" in App.config.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace="TestServiceLibrary")]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        double Add(double n1, double n2);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
}
```

TestService.cs code...............

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace TestServiceLibrary
{
    // NOTE: If you change the class name "Service1" here, you must also update the reference to "Service1" in App.config.
    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            return n1 + n2;
        }
    }
}
```

TestServiceHost.cs (code of console application)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using TestServiceLibrary;

namespace TestServiceHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost myhost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService));

            myhost.Open();

            while (System.Console.ReadKey().Key != System.ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            myhost.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

XML Configuration of app.config... same in both wcf service library and wcf service host(console application in this case..)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TestServiceLibrary.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8731/TestServiceLibrary/TestService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint name="TestService_wsHttpBinding" address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TestServiceLibrary.ITestService">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TestServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Web Client (asp.net client, default.aspx) code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Simple AJAX Service Client Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[

    // This function creates an asynchronous call to the service
    function makeCall(operation){
        var n1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
        var n2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

        // If user filled out these fields, call the service
        if(n1 && n2){

            // Instantiate a service proxy
            var proxy = new TestServiceLibrary.ITestService();

            // Call correct operation on proxy       
            switch(operation){
                case "Add":
                    proxy.Add(parseFloat(n1), parseFloat(n2), onSuccess, onFail, null);            
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    // This function is called when the result from the service call is received
    function onSuccess(mathResult){
        document.getElementById("result").value = mathResult;
    }

    // This function is called if the service call fails
    function onFail(){
        document.getElementById("result").value = "Error";
    }

    // ]]>
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Simple AJAX Service Client Page</h1>
    <p>
        First Number:
        <input type="text" id="num1" /></p>
    <p>
        Second Number:
        <input type="text" id="num2" /></p>
    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" onclick="return makeCall('Add');" value="Add" />
    <p>
        Result:
        <input type="text" id="result" /></p>
    <form id="mathForm" action="" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="http://localhost:8732/TestServiceLibrary/TestService/" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The error Im getting when accessing the webservice through asp.net in ajax is **Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'TestServiceLibrary' is undefined**

Please go through this code and help me in finding the problem. Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: there is a simple sample on the MSDN that may help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410778.aspx

Comment: Preet@ Thanks for the link, i have gone through that in this sample the project is host in iis, but my service is hosted in windows service.

Comment: @coolcake - where the service is hosted shouldn't matter.  As long as your client has the appropriate configuration, it should be able to connect to the service and conduct operations.

Comment: Tim@ Can I find any sample which use wcf service library hosted in windows service and the client written in asp.net ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with my service hosting and the endpoint i'm using.

I should modified my service hosting in the console application to use WebServiceHost instead of ServiceHost, then only the ajax clients can talk to my service. Instead of wsHttpBinding, I should use webHttpBinding.

So the code for webHosting is as follows.

```
using (var host = new WebServiceHost(
  typeof(TestService)))
{
    // Start listening for messages
    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the service.");
    Console.ReadKey();

    // Close the service
    host.Close();
}
```

The xml configuration of my console is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service
          name="TestServiceLibrary.TestService"
          behaviorConfiguration="">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/TestService"
           binding="webHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration=""
           name="TestService_WebHttp"
           contract="TestServiceLibrary.ITestService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now when I did this changes I'm able to call my service through ie using the following url in ie **http://localhost:8732/TestService/Add?n1=20&n2=20** and result returned by it is as follows   **`<double xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">40</double>`**

Finally i found the solution to my problem. Im using JSON as way of communicating data and the script for receiving the data is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mybutton").click(function () {


        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8732/TestService/Add", null, function (result) {


        });

    });     
</script>
```

Comment: Why if I open in browser http://localhost:8732/TestService I got: Endpoint not found.

Answer (score 0):

Use some tool like firebug to determine what is happening with the request. WSHttpBinding is secure by default. Check your security settings. Try first with no security to make sure it is not a security issue.

Comment: Chandermani@ Unfortunately i do not have that much web debugging skills because i'm getting my hands dirty justnow a days. i shall try your suggestion.

Comment: That would be better. It is very much a guessing game right now with the information available. Once you provide more details about the error people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to connect to the service from the AJAX client yet?  If so, are you getting any errors?

Without seeing code, there could be a number of things as Chandermani has said.

I've not done AJAX with WCF, but looking over the article Preet recommended, I would suggest checking (if you haven't already) that your AJAX client has the necessary code as per the article.

Are your service operations decorated with [WebGet]?

Do you have the config file for the AJAX client set up properly?  Is the service's config file set up properly?

Comment: Tim@ Thank you for your help. I have posted the code in the page below. Please help me in identifying the problem.