# Host WCF service in WinForms application

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

I use the same WCF service as here: [How to consume wcf service running as windows service in ajax client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142035/how-to-consume-wcf-service-running-as-windows-service-in-ajax-client)

1. And I want to show All available methods from browser by view h**p://localhost:8732/TestService
   But I get message: **Endpoint not found.**
2. Can I send HTML page with AJAX, which get data from this WCF service, in this service method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is not very clear, could you perhaps reword it a little bit? maybe perhaps post some code?

Also, have you enabled the MEX endpoint? or perhaps it is not  correctly configured. I had a similar problem in which the service appeared to be running but SvcUtil was unable to get any endpoint information. After some reconfiguration (both app.config and code) it worked and SvcUtil could find the endpoint information.